# How to replace specific tag with regex in php?

Tags: php, preg-replace

Suppose I have two links in my content. How can I find the specific links containing the `$string` and replace with words only.

```
$string = 'dog';
$content = 'a quick brown <a href="some-link"> fox</a> jumps over a lazy <a href="another-link"> dog</a>';
$new_content =  preg_replace('<a.+href="(.*)".*> '.$string.'</a>', $string, $content);
```

I have tried with `'~<a.+href="(.*)".*> '.$string.'</a>~'` but its removing all the content between those anchors too.

Whats wrong ?

### update:

replace  `<a href="another-link"> dog</a>` with `dog` only and leave `<a href="some-link"> fox</a>` as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use lazy quantifier, ie `?`, and add delimiter to the regex:

```
$string = 'dog';
$content = 'a quick brown <a href="some-link"> fox</a> jumps over a lazy <a href="another-link"> dog</a>';
$new_content =  preg_replace('~<a.+?href="(.*?)".*> '.$string.'</a>~', $string, $content);
//                         here ___^  and  __^
```

You could also reduce to:

```
$new_content =  preg_replace("~<a[^>]+>\s*$string\s*</a>~", $string, $content);
```

Comment: @AnilChaudhari: Sorry, you have to add optional spaces arround `$string`, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
Try this to replace the anchor text to given string with preg_replace,

$string = 'dog';
$content = 'a quick brown <a href="some-link"> fox</a> jumps over a lazy <a href="another-link"> dog</a>';

echo preg_replace('/<a(.+?)>.+?<\/a>/i',"<a$1>".$string."</a>",$content);
```

Comment: @AnilChaudhari ,yes fox will be replaced with dog.
a quick brown <a href="some-link"> dog</a> jumps over a lazy <a href="another-link"> dog</a>

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. But I just want to find anchor tag with selected string and replace the anchor tag element with given string.